# Car goes silent when I turn the ignition key

Tags: battery, starting, ignition, starter

I have a 1970 Chevelle.  The last few times I have tried to crank the car, I had to jump it off.  I charged the battery and this time when I turned the key, the dash lights came on then as I continued suddenly everything went dead. Not dash lights, no turning over of the start, simply dead.  I hooked up the truck with jumper cables and let it charge for 15 minutes, still no joy, no dash lights or any activity.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the battery connections (loose, corroded etc), what about all the major cables supplying the fuse box / car?

Comment: Yes Sir.  So far I have checked all cables.  I put meter on the battery & it checks as charged.  Terminals are spotless.